# meaning of "let it set up"

Tags: meaning

I wonder the meaning of 'set up' in this sentence.

One chef said like below while he's making mac and cheese.

> Pour it into a hotel pan and let it set up.

And then he cover parchment and put some bowl on the parchment.

what's the meaning of set up? It means just waiting?

Comment: If you could provide a tiny bit more context (i.e. is he pouring the mac and cheese into the hotel pan?) then we could probably answer. My guess right would be "pour it into the hotel pan and let it **settle**" or something like that - but I don't really know much about cooking, so take this with a pinch of salt! (pun intended)

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/set - 4. [NO OBJECT] Harden into a solid or semi-solid state: _'cook for a further thirty-five minutes until the filling has set'_

Comment: @JamesWirth: No more context necessary: it's a cooking term that's understandable as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **set up** means "to thicken, to congeal".  A sauce to which flour has been added will "set up".